# PHP self-creating code, how can I call it?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have some PHP which automatically generates HTML forms per list-item, so basically I load a bunch of items for a SQL database, and I have a form linked to the itemID. However because each Item is different, i.e if a user searches for kettles. It might show itemID = 2, 84, 104 for example. So how can I check if the user submitted a form and do a task for that specific itemID?

Comment: To check if the form was submitted: `if(isset($_POST['submitButtonNameAttribute'])) { // do task }`

Comment: @AmalMurali I cannot do this because the ItemID will always be different...

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `ItemID` whatsoever. The code in first comment was a hint for "How to check if the form was submitted".

Comment: @AmalMurali I know this, My question is though how can I call the code, because I don't know the id. I.e this is our list:                           1) ITEMID  = "32", 2) ITEMID = "87"; How can I get the ID of which ever one the user pressed.

Comment: You use PHP to print the HTML code of the input element and use the ID itself to name that element... ;)

Comment: I think your question needs more clarity. You asked how can you check if the user submitted the form. But after reading the comments it sounds more like you need to know what item the user clicked on in the list so that you can load the item details page.

Comment: Well sort of, but it's not the item details page I want to display. I.e, add items to stock list: then there is a form with an input box, you can then add an amount to the item. How can I get the ID of the form submitted using PHP if the item ID is always different? @pthurmond

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan I know that, but how can I get the name of the element in PHP if I don't know it's ID?

Comment: You can store the IDs in an array and loop thru the array to check if they are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the comments I am going to assume that A) You have presented the user with a list of items (example: e-commerce website listing a bunch of books). And B) You want to allow the user to click on one and then load the details of that item.

This is how it works. When you output the list you don't need a form. You need to generate links to each item. If you don't have or want to use clean URLs associated with the items that is fine. When you output the HTML the item title should be surrounded in an anchor tag. This tag should point to a url like this "http://www.mydomain.com/item/1234" OR "http://www.mydomain.com/item.php?item_number=1234". It doesn't really matter which way you go with this. And this is a very passive way to do this.

Next, you create a controller/page/path/script/whatever that will intercept this path. For simplicities sake we will go the script route. So create your item.php script that connects to your database. In it you will call $_GET['item_number'] to get the item number from the URL. The you will take this item number (which will point to it's ID in the database) and use it in your SQL query once you have sanitized the input (Google how to do that).

Then you will get all the info you need to built your item info page. Or you can use this to take an action on the item. You can load an edit page. You can pass in more parameters in the GET (URL) to specify more specific actions or a larger variety of them.

Comment: Further, if you need to take action on multiple items at a time you could use a form and for each row you output a checkbox input with the same name, such as name="myitem[]". Each input will have a different value but the same name (and you do need the square brackets). Then when the form is submitted (use the POST method) you will get an array of selected values of whichever item was checked.

Comment: Obviously that value being the item ID.